# Does SciPy have any function for extracting data from image?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, image-recognition

I have to analyze the data given as an image like:
[image]

What I do is

1. Earasing the axises manually.
2. Convert the image to (x,y) coordinates by `imagemagick` (collecting the coordinates of black pixels)
3. Adjusting the (x,y) values (according to the axis values (rather than the pixel coordinates), then y direction: in images, the y coordinate increases from top to bottom).
4. Sorting the data by x.
5. Loading the data in a `SciPy` script.

I wonder if there is a function to do any of the steps 1-4 in the same `SciPy` script.

Since `SciPy` has a range of functions for image recognition, I would like to know if there is a function to translate an image into the (x,y) coordinates of the black pixels creating the curve, and so on.

Comment: What do you mean by *convert image to (x,y) coordinates*, and by *adjusting the (x,y) values*?

Comment: @kazemakase The image is made of black pixels, which can be translated as (x,y) values. Since the (0,0) point in the images is the top left side, the y value should be adjusted to have the (0,0) point in the bottom left corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, load the image with [`sp.misc.imread`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html) or PIL so that it resides in a numpy array that I'll refer to as `img` below. (If it is a color image convert it to grayscale with `img = np.mean(img, axis=-1)`. Then:

1. `img = img[:-k, :]  # Erase axes manually, k is the height of the axis in pixels`
2. `y, x = np.where(img == 0)  # Find x and y coordinates of all black pixels`
3. `y -= y.max()  # invert y axis so (0,0) is in the bottom left corner`
4. `i = np.argsort(x); x, y = x[i], y[i]  # Sort data by x`

Assumed imports:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
```